# Android OutOfMemoryError with HashMap and ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, out-of-memory

I am parsing a csv file, more specifically a POI file, using opencsv and reading the info into an ArrayList. I need to cache the information in memory so when a user hits a button I check every POI and see if it is within the current bounds of the mapview. Some POI files can have 10K - 60K rows. I can read about 50K rows before my app force closes, so I set a limit of 30K to leave memory for other things. My issue is when I go to load another file I clear() the Arraylists I trimToSize() and I have tried declaring the ArrayLists as new ArrayLists but the GC never releases the old data from memory. I can clear() them and read a new file into them but something is not allowing the GC to free up the memory. I have no training in programming, IT, or CS. This is the first App I have ever worked on or written in Java / Android. I have worked, read and study for about 6 days now trying to figure out why I have this memory leak. Any help will be appreciated and any suggestion as to how I could optimize my code will also be appreciated as I am a complete noob. Also, the code below only shows the methods of concerning reading the file into memory. You can google opencsv to see the docs on how it works and if you need to see anything else let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks in advance!

```
    public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    private static MapView mapView;
    int counter = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> arrLat = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrLong = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Boolean> arrCheck = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // main.xml contains a MapView
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    //Gets file name from ListOfFiles Activity Class
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                boolean callreadPOIFile = extras.getBoolean("callreadPOIFile");
                if(callreadPOIFile) {
                    String filePath = extras.getString("filePath");
                    readPOIFileInThread(filePath);

                }else{
                    // Show user alert box                      
                }

            }
}

public void readPOIFileInThread(String filePath) {


    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "LOADING:\n" + filePath + "\nPLEASE WAIT...");
    final String finalFilePath = filePath;

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                readPOIFile(finalFilePath);
            }catch(Exception e){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception, readPOIFileInThread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }).start();

}       


//Parse and load POI CSV File
public void readPOIFile(String filePath){


    arrLat.clear();
    arrLong.clear();
    arrName.clear();
    arrInfo.clear();
    arrCheck.clear();

    arrLat.trimToSize();
    arrLong.trimToSize();
    arrName.trimToSize();
    arrInfo.trimToSize();
    arrCheck.trimToSize();

            //arrLat = null;
            //arrLong = null;
            //arrName = null;
            //arrInfo = null;
            //arrCheck = null;

            //arrLat = new ArrayList<String>();
            //arrLong = new ArrayList<String>();
            //arrName = new ArrayList<String>();
            //arrInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
            //arrCheck = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    System.out.println(arrLat.isEmpty());

    String lat = null;
    String lng = null;
    Double dLat;
    Double dLng;
    int lati;
    int lngi;
    String name = null;
    String info = null;

    CSVReader reader = null;
    //System.out.println(filePath);
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // prepare the alert box
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setMessage("There was an error reading file: " + filePath
                + "\n Please check the file format and try again.");

        // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // click listener on the alert box
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // the button was clicked
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // show it
        alertbox.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String [] nextLine = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            //System.out.println(nextLine[0]+ "\n" + nextLine[1]+ "\n"  + nextLine[2]+ "\n"  + nextLine[3] + "\n");

            try {
                lng = nextLine[0];

            } catch (Exception e) {
                lng = Integer.toString(1);
            }

            try {
                lat = nextLine[1];

            } catch (Exception e) {
                lat = Integer.toString(1);
            }
            try {
                name = nextLine[2];

            } catch (Exception e) {
                name = "No Name...";
            }
            try {
                info = nextLine[3];
            } catch (Exception e) {

                info = "No Info...";
            }
            //convert lat and long to double
            try{
                dLat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                dLng = Double.parseDouble(lng);
            }catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println("error converting lat long to Double at row: " + count);
                break;

            }
            //convert lat lng to int
            lati = (int)(dLat * 1E6);
            lngi = (int)(dLng * 1E6);

            //add line to ArrayLists
            try{
            arrLat.add(Integer.toString(lati));
            arrLong.add(Integer.toString(lngi));
            arrName.add(name);
            arrInfo.add(info);
            arrCheck.add(false);
            }catch (Exception e){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error reading. Please check the file. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("Error reading file.");

                    }
                });
            }
            count++;
            if(count == 10000 || count == 20000){
                final int showcount = count;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), showcount + " POI's loaded",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
                    }
                });
            }

            if(count == 30000)
                break;

            System.out.println(count);
        }
        final String toastFilePath = filePath;
        final int toastcount = count;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(toastcount > 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File: " + toastFilePath + " read... \n"
                            + toastcount + " point(s) were loaded...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INVALIDE FILE!\nFile: " + toastFilePath + " read... \n"
                            + toastcount + " points.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });



    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

FIXED:

I finaly found my issue! After studying activity life cycles a I found that a new instance was being created every time I would go to my list activity to pick a file and cache it I was creating a new instance of my MainActivity. I set my MainActivity to singleTop mode in the manifest and moved some code the the onNewIntent() method and all is well. My app now works great!

Comment: Any particular reason you're not reading that CSV file into a database table and querying the database instead?

Comment: I haven't tried reading it into a db. I did a little research before starting and found many posts of people having to much lag. I finaly found my issue! After studying activity life cycles a I found that a new instance was being created every time I would go to my list activity to pick a file and cache it I was creating a new instance of my MainActivity. I set my MainActivity to singleTop mode in the manifest and moved some code the the onNewIntent() method and all is well. My app now works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and the static reference to my Mapview and removing static changed nothing except it broke my getter and setter. I finaly found my issue! After studying activity life cycles a I found that a new instance was being created every time I would go to my list activity to pick a file and cache it I was creating a new instance of my MainActivity. I set my MainActivity to singleTop mode in the manifest and moved some code the the onNewIntent() method and all is well. My app now works great!

Answer (score 4):

some advices:

1. **do not have a static reference to a View** object (or a drawable , or anything that has a reference to context) . it's a very bad practive which could easily get you to memory leaks .reason:
   even after leaving the activity , there is a static reference to a view which references to the activity that you've left,including all of its fields(your large collections , for example). read [**here**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) for more info.
2. do you really have to read the entire file , and store its entire content into the memory? of course it's easy for you and much faster than anything else , but it can easily take a lot of memory , especially if you use it this way . try to **read only what you need** , and **store only what you need**.
3. watch [**google's**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html) video for showing how to find & handle memory leaks
4. do you really have to store the data in strings? how about just the values that need to be checked (coordinates,perhaps?) or a **collection of Pois** , each has its own fields (id,name,coordinates,...) ? a string in java is an array of characters , each takes 2 bytes (since it's unicode) , so it can take a lot of space in the memory .as an example, 60000 rows times 80 characters times 2 bytes per character is 9,600,000 bytes , which is almost **10MB** . you need to be tighter in memory usage. remember that it's a mobile platform which has memory efficiency in one of its top priorities (for better tasks switching) .

   using a collection of Pois will not only be better in design perspective (easier to read , understand , maintain,...) . it will also take less space - using primitives instead of wrappers (int instead of Integer, for example) .

Comment: this solution might work , but it might also ruin your activities flows design . consider checking if you really must have the mapView stored , and instead use the data that it needs . also , try to set flags on the manifest that will prevent the activity from being re-created (like those of the configuration change) .

Answer (score 2):

Couple thoughts:

1. `Integer.toString(1)` can be replaced with `"1"` which will take advantage of the String pool.
2. Instead of storing all of your values as `String`s, have you tried using primitives?
3. `lat` and `lng` sounds like you're trying to store latitude and longitude. Perhaps you want to use a `Double` for that.
4. Instead of using an `ArrayList`, you could try allocating a static-sized array and store the length.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the CSVReader implementation, but it never gets closed in readPOIFile.  If it's hanging on to stuff it could cause a memory problem for you.